# 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable`

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, relay-chain

[image: Screenshot]

I've added `pallet-nft` and `pallet-uniques` in Relay Chain. All the things are working fine but when I'm signing the transaction in the `pallet-uniques` `fn create(collection,admin)`, it is showing me this error:

> 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed WASM backtrace: 0: 0x547257 - !rust_begin_unwind 1: 0x54ee - !core::panicking::panic_fmt::hca80ede79c2b9c5b 2: 0x29ff1c - !TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction : RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n 0: 0x547257 - !rust_begin_unwind\n 1: 0x54ee

Comment: Could you paste the entire error message in as text too, it will be useful for searches in the future.

Comment: 1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed WASM backtrace: 0: 0x547257 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind 1: 0x54ee - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::hca80ede79c2b9c5b 2: 0x29ff1c - <unknown>!TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction : RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n 0: 0x547257 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n 1: 0x54ee -

Comment: Edit the the post and put it in the question

Comment: Try refreshing polkadot-js. Do you have added the pallets through a runtime upgrade?

Comment: No i've added locally before starting the chain

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify custom `types.json` in `polkadot.js.org`. These links might be helpful:

1. https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.extend/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487857/how-to-generate-types-json-in-substrate

Also, try to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your implementation of WeightInfo in runtime/src.

In my case, I had a runtime/src/weight.rs file with some functions left without weight benchmarking, I just had a bunch of todo!() macros. The problem was resolved when I replaced them with actual weights.